# DirectX SDK / VS2013 SDK setup

Tags: directx

I am a beginning programmer university student and I want to apply myself outside of class with a side project. I wanted to start programming some simple directX stuff in C++ for practice and preparation for future classes.

However, I have Visual Studios 2013 installed and the DirectX SDK June version installed, and I can't seem to find any directX templates in visual studios.  In tutorials I have watched, when a person goes into visual studios 2013 and clicks on "Visual C++", they have a lot more templates show up, including DirectX ones.

What step am I missing to be able to see these things in my Visual Studios 2013 professional?

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in templates for desktop DirectX, since you have installed the DirectX SDK, I recommend you use the Samples/Demos from the SDK(you can find it from DirectX Sample Browser), there is a sample called Empty Project, you can install that sample and write your code based on it.

[image]

Comment: You may want to check out [Direct3D Win32 Game Visual Studio template](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2015/01/06/direct3d-win32-game-visual-studio-template.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

There are only templates for DirectX Windows Store Apps. I cannot remember if it ever was DirectX Desktop templates in Visual Studio.
On a picture [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/WDC-DirectX-game-learning-7cf9bdce) you can see two default DirectX Windows Store Apps templates and new templates which you can to download.

Probably, in your tutorial there are some home made templates, or those which can be fond on a web. You can easily [make your own template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/s365byhx%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) too.

If you really want to learn program for Desktop (and as you are trying to use DirectX SDK it is probably what you want), just follow the code that you can find in books and tutorials. Also it is a good idea not to copy any code, but to start your own projects(s) which will develop as long as you will develop your knowledge.

<sub>Note, that DirectX SDK was deprecated a while ago (latest version is dating June 2010). You must use Windows SDK for any new code. Though, you can compile old samples (which requires stuff not present in new SDK) with DirectX SDK. You could find interesting some of Q&A on that topic:</sub>

- <sub>[DirectX SDK vs Windows SDK: which one to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20362041)</sub>
- <sub>[Working with Direct X and VS2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18092633)</sub>

<sub>and this blog on MSDN by [Chuck Walbourn - MSFT](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw) :</sub>

- <sub>[Where is the DirectX SDK?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/03/22/where-is-the-directx-sdk.aspx)</sub>
- <sub>[Where is the DirectX SDK (2013 Edition)?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/07/01/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2013-edition.aspx)</sub>
- <sub>[Living without D3DX](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/08/21/living-without-d3dx.aspx)</sub>

Happy coding! ;)

Comment: DirectX SDKs usually came with a few example apps and some kind of demo library. Those could be used to spawn template projects (pretty much similar to the classic project wizard in the IDE), although I think this has never been built into the VS IDE (except for the XNA SDKs).

Comment: I see.  Up until now I had been doing all my own coding and learning from books, but from the tutorials I watched for DirectX I thought I was missing some key components needed to work with directX.  For example, when I would make a game in the console window, I would select "Visual C++" then the "Win32 Console application", then start coding away.

From the tutorials it looked like I was missing required files or something, as his C++ template list was much larger than mine and was using one I didn't have.  I guess that is not the case.

Thanks for the feedback!  I appreciate it!